# SQL join using prepared statement

Tags: php

I have 3 tables jobseeker, certification and education which i want to query using prepared statement. This is my code

```
$username= $_SESSION['username'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT jobseeker.username ,  jobseeker.first_name , jobseeker.last_name , education.university , certification.institution ,  from jobseeker inner join education on jobseeker.username=education.jobseeker_username inner join certification on jobseeker.username=certification.jobseeker_username where username=:username");
$query->bindParam(':username' , $username);
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $data;
```

it isn't working.

Comment: add prefix in where condition "tablename.username"

Comment: specify table name before username column

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Ya. @Faran and also Poria Thanks its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your query, erase the comma `,` before `from jobseeker` that is making the query fail.

```
SELECT jobseeker.username ,  jobseeker.first_name , jobseeker.last_name , education.university , certification.institution  from jobseeker inner join education on jobseeker.username=education.jobseeker_username inner join certification on jobseeker.username=certification.jobseeker_username where username=:username
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in your query. 
**Correct Query**

```
SELECT jobseeker.username ,  jobseeker.first_name , jobseeker.last_name , education.university , certification.institution  
From jobseeker 
    INNER JOIN education 
      ON 
        jobseeker.username = education.jobseeker_username 
    INNER JOIN certification 
      ON 
        jobseeker.username = certification.jobseeker_username 
    where 
        jobseeker.username = :username
```